# if record ouputting as NaT in pandas, skip record

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium

I have a few records outputting in my pandas data frame as `NaT`.

*i.e.*  `Date_Refused_Final_Something_of_ICP=NaT,`

And it seems to disrupt my script. I would simply like to skip these few records found as Nat, and continue with the rest of the records/script.

Below is the complete relevant code:

```
def get_excel_data(self):
    """Places excel data into pandas dataframe"""
    excel_data = pandas.read_excel(self.find_file())

    columns = pandas.DataFrame(columns=excel_data.columns.tolist())
    excel_data = pandas.concat([excel_data, columns])

    excel_data.columns = excel_data.columns.str.strip()
    excel_data.columns = excel_data.columns.str.replace("/", "_")
    excel_data.columns = excel_data.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")

    num_valid_records = 0

    for row in excel_data.itertuples():
        mrn = row.MRN

        if mrn in ("", " ", "N/A", None) or math.isnan(mrn):
            print(f"Invalid record: {row}")
            excel_data = excel_data.drop(excel_data.index[row.Index])
        else:
            num_valid_records += 1

    print(f"Processing #{num_valid_records} records")

    return self.clean_data_frame(excel_data)

def clean_data_frame(self, data_frame):
    """Cleans up dataframes"""
    for col in data_frame.columns:
        if "date" in col.lower():
            data_frame[col] = pandas.to_datetime(data_frame[col],
                                                 errors='coerce', infer_datetime_format=True)
            data_frame[col] = data_frame[col].dt.date
    data_frame['MRN'] = data_frame['MRN'].astype(int).astype(str)

    return data_frame

def get_mapping_data(self):
    map_data = pandas.read_excel(config.MAPPING_DOC, sheet_name='main')
    columns = pandas.DataFrame(columns=map_data.columns.tolist())
    return pandas.concat([map_data, columns])
```

Comment: Where within your loops will it find this `NaT`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're encountering this, but you can simply put `continue` when it finds this:

```
if mrn in ("", " ", "N/A", None) or math.isnan(mrn):
            print(f"Invalid record: {row}")
            continue  # <--- if it encounters any of the conditions above, it skips and goes to the next row in your excel_data
```

Comment: Woah, woah; what if I don't want to skip the entire ROW, if encountered; but rather just the cell!?

Comment: try changing the `continue` to `pass`. I'm not sure if that'll cause an error further in the code. I guess my question then would be is if you're putting this into a dataframe, there would need to be some value in that cell. I'm guess I'm just having trouble since I don;t know what your input excel file looks like, and what you want as your output dataframe to look like. Is it possible to share that?